# Send emails from two distinct columns using data in google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript

Good morning.

Very new coder with little background.  I need to merge data from a google spreadsheet into an email, without using an add-on.  I borrowed this code from a site and I'm able to produce an email but it will only pull from the first email address column. I need to send an email to both the manager and director.  Their email address will be stored in two separate columns with unique labels.  I can't change the spreadsheet data as the spreadsheet is storing responses pulled from a survey form that is already in progress (example column layout below):

Name / Email Address / Director Name / Director Email Address / Response 1 / Response 2 / etc...

Everything I've researched will send an email from one column, but not two, or a "cc".

Below is the borrowed code.  Would very much appreciate any help on how to modify the code to send the "response" data to both the Manager and Director in one email.

kind regards,
KA

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 15);

  var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

// Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
    var objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

// For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
// it to the appropriate person.
   for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
// Get a row object
   var rowData = objects[i];

// Generate a personalized email.
// Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
// the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
   var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
   var emailSubject = "Data Survey";

MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText);

 }
}


// Replaces markers in a template string with values define in a JavaScript data object.
// Arguments:
//   - template: string containing markers, for instance ${"Column name"}
//   - data: JavaScript object with values to that will replace markers. For instance
//           data.columnName will replace marker ${"Column name"}
// Returns a string without markers. If no data is found to replace a marker, it is
// simply removed.
   function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
   var email = template;
// Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance ${"Column name"}
   var templateVars = template.match(/\$\{\"[^\"]+\"\}/g);

 // Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
 // If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
   for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
 // normalizeHeader ignores ${"} so we can call it directly here.
   var variableData = data[normalizeHeader(templateVars[i])];
   email = email.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
 }

   return email; 
 }





//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range;
// Returns an Array of objects.
 function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
 columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
 var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
 var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
 var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
 return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
 function getObjects(data, keys) {
   var objects = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
   var object = {};
   var hasData = false;
 for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
  var cellData = data[i][j];
  if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
    continue;
  }
  object[keys[j]] = cellData;
  hasData = true;
}
if (hasData) {
  objects.push(object);
   }
  }
 return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
  function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
 if (key.length > 0) {
  keys.push(key);
 }
}
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
  function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
 var letter = header[i];
 if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
  upperCase = true;
  continue;
}
if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
  continue;
}
if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
  continue; // first character must be a letter
}
if (upperCase) {
  upperCase = false;
  key += letter.toUpperCase();
} else {
  key += letter.toLowerCase();
  }
 }
 return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
   function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
 return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
 }

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
 function isAlnum(char) {
 return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
 char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
 isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
   function isDigit(char) {
 return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation : [Mail App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app), the recipent represents the addresses of the recipients, separated by commas

So in order to send to several recipents, just make a string separated by comma:`mike@example.com, mike2@example.com`

You could pick the rows you want and do something like this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(rowData[0].emailAddress + ',' + rowData[1].emailAdress, emailSubject, emailText);
```

Comment: hi and thank you for responding.  When you say "pick the rows" -  if the first group of email addresses have a column label "email address" and they are in column B of the spreadsheet, and the second group of email addresses, the column is labeled "your director's email" and is column J of the email, could you show how that should look in the code?

Comment: @user4458476 you want to send one mail to all e-mails in B column and another to all e-mails in J?